# Access element in list using indexes stored in another list

Tags: python, list

I'm looking for a general way to access elements in a list using indexes stored in another list.

For example, I have the list:

```
b = [[[[[0.2], [3]], [[4.5], [78]], [[1.3], [0.23]], [[6.], [9.15]]],
[[[3.1], [44]], [[1.], [66]], [[0.18], [2.3]], [[10], [7.5]]],
[[[3], [4.]], [[12.3], [12]], [[7.8], [3.7]], [[1.2], [2.1]]]]]
```

and I need to access the element whose index are stored in:

```
c = [0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
```

that is:

```
3
```

This won't work:

```
b[c[0]][c[1]][c[2]][c[3]][c[4]]
```

because the shape of `b` changes with every run of my code, which is why I need a *general* way of using `c` to access the element in `b`.

Something like:

```
b[*c]
```

that I would've bet would work, but it doesn't.

Comment: b[*c] won't work unless you redefine `b` as an object and redefine its `__getitem__` method

Comment: I'm not married to that way of doing it, I just thought it would work. Any _general_ way of using `c` to access an element in `b` would be fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [reduce](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) (or [functools.reduce](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) for forward-compatible with Python 3)

```
>>> def getitems(data, keys):
...     return reduce(lambda a, b: a[b], [data]+keys)
... 
>>> getitems(b, c)
3
```

This assumes that `keys` is always a list.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a recursive function. A recursive function is a function that calls itself. In this case, each time I call the function, I decrease the dimension of its two arguments.

```
b = [[[[[0.2], [3]], [[4.5], [78]], [[1.3], [0.23]], [[6.], [9.15]]],
[[[3.1], [44]], [[1.], [66]], [[0.18], [2.3]], [[10], [7.5]]],
[[[3], [4.]], [[12.3], [12]], [[7.8], [3.7]], [[1.2], [2.1]]]]]

c = [0, 0, 0, 1, 0]

def getitem(arr, indices):
    if isinstance(indices, int):
        return arr[indices]
    if len(indices) == 1:
        return arr[indices[0]]
    item = indices[0]
    new_indices = indices[1:]
    return getitem(arr[item], new_indices)

print getitem(b, c) ## prints 3
```

Comment: The other answer is simpler so I've selected it, but you have introduced me to a concept I wasn't aware of in python: recursive functions. Thanks!